# How to loop through custom posts in Wordpress and display according to page title

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know how you would display a custom post type according to what post type you are on?

For example if I go to my www.url.com/services/digital page I want to show the digital portfolio or if I go to my www.url.com/services/audio page I want to show the audio portfolio.

Just to clarify I have two post types -

1. Services
2. Portfolio

The code I have wrote works fine but surely there must be a simpler way to do it as I have six categories I don't want to write out this code six different times on the same page

```
    <?php

        if ( is_single( 'digital' ) ) {

            $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page'=>'3', cat=>'9') );

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                echo'<div class="group service_portfolio">';

                    echo'<div class="service_portfolio_left">';

                        echo '<h2 style="color:#52514e; font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo'Client'; echo'</h2>';

                        echo'<p style="color:#757573; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo the_title(); echo'</p>';

                        echo '<h2 style="color:#52514e; font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo'What we done'; echo'</h2>';

                        echo '<p style="color:#757573; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo the_field('what_was_done'); echo'</p>';

                        echo'<h2 style="color:#52514e; font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo'See for yourself'; echo'</h2>';

                        echo '<p class"bottom_p">'; echo'<a href="http://'; the_field('portfolio_url'); echo'">'; echo the_field('portfolio_url'); echo' </a>'; echo '</p>';

                    echo'</div>';

                echo'<div class="service_portfolio_left" style="text-align:right;">';

                echo the_post_thumbnail();

                echo'</div>';

                echo'</div>';


                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }

                ?>

   <!-- Output print work -->

    <?php

        if ( is_single( 'print' ) ) {

            $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page'=>'3', cat=>'10') );  

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                echo'<div class="group service_portfolio">';

                    echo'<div class="service_portfolio_left">';

                        echo '<h2 style="color:#52514e; font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo'Client'; echo'</h2>';

                        echo'<p style="color:#757573; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo the_title(); echo'</p>';

                        echo '<h2 style="color:#52514e; font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo'What we done'; echo'</h2>';

                        echo '<p style="color:#757573; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo the_field('what_was_done'); echo'</p>';

                        echo'<h2 style="color:#52514e; font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:5%;">'; echo'See for yourself'; echo'</h2>';

                        echo '<p class"bottom_p">'; echo'<a href="http://';  the_field('portfolio_url'); echo'">'; echo the_field('portfolio_url'); echo' </a>'; echo '</p>';

                    echo'</div>';

                echo'<div class="service_portfolio_left" style="text-align:right;">';

                echo the_post_thumbnail();

                echo'</div>';

                echo'</div>';


                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }

                ?>
```

Comment: To be clear you want to use the same page template for all six pages? Are you sure that in the end that's what you'll want to do?

Comment: Yeah it's one page template - basically theres six pages that are all to look the same, they are "services" that my client provides..

1. Digital
2. Audio
3. Print
4. Social Media
5. PR
6. Content Marketing

On these page I also want to show portfolio items related to that service hence the code above..

Comment: How did you associate standard categories with the custom post types?

Comment: I used cat=>'9' within the array to get the category 'digital'

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that you want to use a 6x archive templates (`archive-services.php`, `archive-digital.php` etc.) since that is the standard way of presenting CPTs and it removes the need to the conditional and query parts. Then in each one of those you can use a [template part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) the markup within the loop; this way you can reuse the same markup for all 6x templates easily, using:

```
<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>
```

Doing it this way gives you some flexibility whilst avoiding all the repetition. So your 6x archive templates might look like this:

```
<?php
    get_header();

    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'loop', 'preview' );

    endwhile; endif;

    get_footer();
?>
```

That will load `loop-preview.php`, which will contain the mark up to go within the loop.

**EDIT:** @AndrewBartel's comment made me realised that I was over-thinking this. If the 6x categories you mentioned are *only* being used for your custom post types, then you can create 6x category templates instead (`category-digital.php`, `category-audio.php` etc.) These will display *all* posts that are within that category. That will probably be the most straightforward way of handling it; the template part bit is still valid. Check the [WP Codex entry for templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for more info.

Comment: I've just realised you're more interested in displaying different *categories*, not different post types, so I might need to rethink my answer...

Comment: You can just do category-{post-type}.php

Comment: Something along the line?

<?php

if ( is_single( 'digital' ) ) {

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page'=>'3', cat=>'9') );

else if ( is_single( 'audio' ) ) {

   $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page'=>'3', cat=>'10') );
               
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

echo'ALL MY CODE ETC HERE TO DISPLAY PORTFOLIO';

                

                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }
                }
                }

                ?>

Comment: @AndrewBartel Does that work? I was under the impression that the category templates work with term IDs and slugs. However, if those terms are *only* being used for those particular CPTs, then your approach would work, e.g. if the 'digital' category is only used for 'portfolio' post types, then `category-digital.php` would work fine.

Comment: @Kieren You're approach would work. However, WP's template system is built for exactly this kind of functionality and takes care of the URL schemes as well, which is why I favour it. If you did want to use your example, I'd change it slightly by using `get_term_by($slug)` to fetch the category numbers for me, rather than having to hard code them in myself. That way if they change for any reason, or new categories are added it will take care of itself. That way you could also remove the multiple `if` statements and just pass the term idea directly to the query.

Comment: Hi Dre, thanks for your answer but how exactly would that fit into the query...?

Something along the lines of

<?php

 $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page'=>'3', 'category_name'=>'cat-slug') );  

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    }

                    ?>

This doesn't seem to work - the only I can do it is with six if statements - very frustrating!

Thanks again :-)